# When K = $\bar{E}$ \ U , U $\supset$ $\bar{E}$ \ E . Prove K $\subset$ E

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove K $\subset$ E , when K = $\bar{E}$  \ U , U $\supset$ $\bar{E}$ \ E , $\bar{E}$ is the closure of E.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The fact that $\bar E$ is the closure of $E$ is irrelevant. All you really need to know is that $E\subseteq\bar E$, $U\supseteq\bar E\setminus E$, and $K=\bar E\setminus U$. You want to show that $K\subseteq E$, so suppose that $x\in K$. Then $x\in\bar E$, and $x\notin U$. $U\supseteq\bar E\setminus E$, so if $x\notin U$, then $x\notin\ldots$ what? The answer to that question, combined with the fact that $x\in\bar E$, will give you what you need to finish the argument.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about the irrelevant of closure of E. What I attempted yesterday was :  $U^C$ $\subset$ $(\bar{E} \cap E^C)^C$ , then K = $\bar{E} \cap U^C \subset \bar{E} \cap (E \cup \bar{E}^C)$ = E

Comment: @Peter: You can do that, but you’re working harder than necessary. If $x\notin U$, and $U\supseteq\bar E\setminus E$, then clearly $x\notin\bar E\setminus E$; you don’t have to manipulate complements to get that. Now what things aren’t in $\bar E\setminus E$? Things that aren’t in $\bar E$ in the first place, and things that are in $\bar E$ but are **also** in $E$. You know that $x\in\bar E$, so ... ?